# Getting StormCrawler to retrieve more body content from a web page and put it into Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, stormcrawler

I have a Proof of Concept Stormcrawler install pointing at one of our smaller university websites ( https://example.com - around 300 pages), and am having issues with the amount of info SC is pulling from the body content. This site has a ton of menus at the top of the page, and SC is only getting most of the way through extracting the menu content before it cuts off and never actually gets to the real body content of the page. Is there a way to tell SC to grab a larger amount of body content from the page?  Or is the issue on the Elasticsearch side? I currently have the SC/ES install set up just like the tutorial you have posted.

Thanks!
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably due to the config of *http.content.limit* which has a value of 65K in the [config generated by the artefact](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/crawler-conf.yaml#L46).

You can set it to -1 so that the entire content is preserved.

I noticed from a page of that site that the main content is in a MAIN element. You could configure the [ContentParseFilter](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/resources/parsefilters.json#L20) so that it extracts the text from these elements and use it as the text of the document if found. This way you won't be indexing text from the boilerplate into ES.

Comment: So adding something like this would help with the MAIN element? `"pattern4": "//MAIN"` under the ContentParseFilter? Or should I put it first and make it pattern1?

Comment: I ask because I made the change you mentioned to the ContentParseFilter in the parsefilters.json in the src/main/resources folder, then I ran `mvn clean package` and the changes showed up in the target/classes directory.  I then cleared out the ES indexes, re-seeded the status index, and re-ran the crawl, and still I get what appears to be the same menu info appearing as the content...starting like this: `"_source": {
"content": "Saunders College of Business About College Overview Saunders Mission Accreditation Accreditation & Memberships AACSB Program Goals..."` etc etc etc...

Comment: it stops at the first match so if any of the previous patterns matched on a wider span, these would take precedence.  the expression above looks correct though.